# Manually count characters for a palindrome

Tags: c++, palindrome, strlen

I currently have a program to detect if a string entered is a palindrome or not. I want to avoid using the strlen method.

```
    int main ()
    {
    char string[80];
    bool Beginning;

Beginning = true;

while (Beginning)
    {
    cout << "\nEnter a string\n" << endl;
        cin.getline(string, 80);
            cout << "\nYou entered: ";
                printf(string, 80);
                    cout << endl;
    if('E' == string[0])  
        {
        if('N' == string [1]) 
            {
            if('D' == string[2])
                break;
            }
         }

    int len=strlen(string);   //avoid this method

    bool flag = true;

for (int c=0; string[c]; c++)
{
    if (flag)
    {
    if(string[c] != string[len-c-1])
            {
            flag = false;
            }
    }
        else
            {
            break;
            }
    }

    if (flag)
    {
        printf ("\nThis is a Palindrome\n");
            Beginning = true;
            continue;
    }
else 
    {
    printf("\nThis is not a palindrome\n");
        Beginning = true;
            continue;
    }
cin.get();

    }
}
```

I have tried manual counting with the following:

```
while (string[c] < '\0') {
c++;
int len = string[c];
}
```

The above messes up the programs ability to accurately determine if a string is a palindrome or not, it will say both of them are not, or are.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using strlen? Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Yes and I'm not ashamed of it haha. Not using the strlen actually isn't even part of the requirements, but is something he threw out there as a challenge for us to get. As always, i don't want to just be handed the answer, i want to know how it works. I always like to understand what the code is doing rather than copy and pasting someones code in with no idea of how it functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need a correct implementation for `len`

This will do the job:

```
len =0;
while (string[++len] );
```

All you need is to check for null termination (as you're using C-strings )

Suggestion: ***Please*** don't mix C & C++ !

Comment: This worked perfectly. I think i was making it out to be more complicated than it needed to be. I already understand how this works, so no need to ask for an explanation. I appreciate the help as always :)